# Connect to Firebird database with c# asp.net throws type initializer exception

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, firebird, dbconnection

I am trying to open a connection to a Firebird database in my c# asp.net web application. It throws an error "The type initializer for 'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.TimeoutHelper' threw an exception."

I am new to Firebird.

In `web.config` I have:

```
  <add name="FireBirdConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Charser=NONE;Database=D:\data\SAMPLE.fdb" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
```

I have installed **FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-4.5.1.0** and have added a namespace of

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
```

I am opening the connection like below:

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(conString))
        {
         con.Open();
        }
```

But this shows me an error as **The type initializer for 'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.TimeoutHelper**

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I need to open the connection.

Even in connection string

[image]

and I have that path in my desktop too

[image]

Thank You..!

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @BenRobinson have updated in question..!!

Comment: Click the View Detail link in the screenshot and post what it says, that is the detail of the exception and provides the information needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @BenRobinson have updated ..!!

Comment: Are you sure that conString is not null or it has right path ?

Comment: @mybirthname Yes,conString is not null and yes in that same path i hvae the file too..:(

Comment: You are using the provider for NET 4.5.1, are you using this version of the NET Framework in your project settings?

Comment: @Steve How to check that in web application???

Comment: Right click the project name in the solution explorer window and check what value is set in the Target Framework combo

Comment: @Steve but this wont be available in website project na??

Comment: Most likely you are using the .NET 4.5 version on .NET 4, or the other way around. And this information is available in a web app project

Comment: @Steve Although the .net version is the most likely problem, `4.5.1.0` is the version of `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient`, not - necessarily - of .net.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am not an expert here so you have probably a clearer vision of the situation, just found some links on internet when you search for that error message that points to a versioning problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented earlier, you are probably using the .NET 4.5 version in a .NET 4 project. You either need to switch your project to .NET 4.5 (which requires Visual Studio 2012 or 2013), or you need to replace the `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` library with the .NET 4 version.

I'd suggest you use NuGet to install it, as this will verify - install time - which variant you need. Otherwise you need to pick the second link from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/ (iirc the first link only installs and includes the .NET 4.5 version).